# permanently append text to a UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring

I'm trying a create a UITextView that upon selection adds the users handle to the beginning of the text.

I understand it is possible to create another UITextView and place it to the left of the second UITextView to make it *look* like they are part of the same range but for formatting purposes it would be much easier if both parts were part of the same textview...

Here's the function I'm using along with an example of it being used.

```
func addHandle(text:String, handle:String) -> NSAttributedString {

    let convertedText = NSMutableAttributedString()

    let h = NSMutableAttributedString(string: handle)
    h.beginEditing()

    let m = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
    m.beginEditing()


    do {
        m.addAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.init(name: "PingFangSC-Regular", size: 18)], range: (m.string as NSString).range(of: m.string))
        h.addAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.init(name: "PingFangSC-Medium", size: 18)], range: (h.string as NSString).range(of: h.string))

        convertedText.append(h)
        convertedText.append(m)

        m.endEditing()
        h.endEditing()
    }
    return convertedText
}

let myHandle = "Johnny: "
let myMessage = "This is a test"

addHandle(text: myMessage, handle: myHandle)
```

In this scenario the both handle and message are able to be concatenated.

However when the text is changed, as seen below, since the handle is part of the new text it runs the function again and adds the handle again.

```
func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    let currentString: String = textView.text!
    self.t.searchBar.attributedText = addHandle(text: currentString, handle: "Johnny: ")
}

 func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {

    let currentString: String = textView.text!
    self.t.searchBar.attributedText = addHandle(text: currentString, handle: "Johnny: ")

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.15, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseOut, animations: {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion: { (completed) in

    })
}
```

How should I go about modifying the my function or implementation to ensure that

1. The handle is always first before the message
2. The user cannot erase the handle from the text

The following should be possible:

**Johhny:** Test Message

**Johnny:**

This should not be possible

**Johnn**

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**
Here's a screenshot displaying the current behavior.
The handle is "Johnny: "and the text typed was "This"

[image]

Comment: A good start to your question. I understand what you wish to do, and the code looks good (so far). But - how can I reproduce the issue you are facing? I have no idea what it is. (I get what should not be possible. But how do I reproduce it?)

Comment: @dfd If you use an actual textfield and type text the problem occurs. I think the problem is my implementation of the function within the UITextViewDelegate methods. I will include a screen shot in an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use something like that (note I used textField, but you can made the same for textView):

```
public func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
   var newString = (textField.text! as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
   if !newString.hasPrefix(handle) {
       newString = "\(handle): \(newString)"
   }
   textView.text = newString

   // Optional font color change for the handle
   let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: textView.text!, attributes: [ NSFontAttributeName : generalFont, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: textView.textColor ]);
   attributedString.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: anotherFont, range: NSMakeRange(0, handle.characters.count));
   textView.attributedText = attributedString
   return false
}
```

Also you can try to check `range` and deny editing (return false) if the range covers the first characters of the string (where you handle is placed).

Comment: I like this approach and I did get it to work however it is still lacking the use of `NSMutableAttributedString()` I think the answer lies in setting different attributes for different ranges but I'm unsure of how to do that.

Comment: @Stefan Add something like that before `return`: `let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: textView.text ,
                                                         attributes: [
                                                            NSFontAttributeName : generalFont,
                                                            NSForegroundColorAttributeName: textView.textColor
            ])
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: anotherFont, range: NSMakeRange(0, handle.characters.count)); textView.attributedText = attributedString`

Answer (score 0):

Please check :

```
funs textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {

    let myHandle = "Johnny: "
    let substringRange: NSRange = (textView.text as NSString).range(of: myHandle)
    if range.location >= substringRange.location && range.location <= substringRange.location + substringRange.length - 1 {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```